# How get sum of field in the related table in one query in Yii2

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

Everyone,
I have 2 tables, that related via third:
Structure looks like below:

```
Playlist: id, channel_id, name, date
Files: id, name, duration
Playlist-rel-Files: list_id, file_id
```

I'm using ActiveRecord in my app. When I use such query to get last playlist:

```
$pl = Playlist::find()
                ->where(['channel_id' => $model->channel_id])
                ->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])
                ->limit(1)
                ->one();
```

Then I use such code to get all files, that related with last playlist:

```
$f = $pl->files;
```

All is OK, and I get Array of files, but I don't need the list of them, I need only SUM of files duration, to get this SUM, I will need to run through array in foreach, my question is:

how can I modify my first query to get Playlist data AND sum of duration of this playlist's files in one query ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a statistical query. You can define a new relation for your count e.g

```
public function getFileCount() {
    return $this->hasMany(Files::className(), ['id' => 'file_id'])
                ->viaTable('playlist-rel-files', ['playlist_id' => 'id'])
                ->sum('duration');
}
```

This is then accessible using the magic property `$fileCount` and can be added to the query via `with` for eager loading i.e:

```
$pl = Playlist::find()
            ->with('fileCount')
            ->where(['channel_id' => $model->channel_id])
            ->orderBy(['date' => SORT_DESC])
            ->one();
```